# How to get my script to start up!

Tags: startup

I am trying to get a simple script to run at startup my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          litecoind daemon
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: start litecoind
# Description:
### END INIT INFO</pre>

do start()
{
litecoind -daemon --start
}

exit 0
```

I've added it to /etc/init.d/litecoin

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/litecoin
sudo update-rc.d litecoin defaults
```

For some reason it is not starting up, forgive my ignorance first time using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you wrote the script or took it somewhere, but the "do start()" is not a part of bash script syntax. I think you can be resumed to
`I don't know if you wrote the script or took it somewhere, but the "do start()" is not a part of bash script syntax. I believe you can be resumed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
litecoind -daemon --start
exit 0
```

Please replace for that and try again. It's also a good idea checking if the script is working by running it in the terminal with the command `$ sudo /etc/init.d/litecoin`

Comment: Thanks ran the new command in terminal and it works but when I update it for boot I get the following  ltc@openltc:~$ sudo update-rc.d -f litecoin defaults
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/litecoin missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/litecoin ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20litecoin -> ../init.d/litecoin
   /etc/rc1.d/K20litecoin -> ../init.d/litecoin
   /etc/rc6.d/K20litecoin -> ../init.d/litecoin
   /etc/rc2.d/S20litecoin -> ../init.d/litecoin
   /etc/rc3.d/S20litecoin -> ../init.d/litecoin